# How do the C++ STL relational operators compare stacks?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, stack

Say I have two stacks:

```
stack<int> s1, s2;
```

And then I push some values in them:

```
s1.push(2);
s1.push(4);
s1.push(5);

s2.push(1);
s2.push(2);
s2.push(10);
```

When I compare them like this `bool isEqual = (s1 > s2);` it yields `True`. But why? Not all of s1's elements are larger than the respective s2 elements, nor is the sum of all elements larger that s2's. What is the exact method of comparison between STL data structures.

P.S. I guess this also applies to queues, deques, lists as well.

Comment: Why not [read a reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/operator_cmp)?

Comment: Well presented question but downvote for RTFM

Answer (score 5):

If you read the documentation for [`operator>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/operator_cmp) it says

> lexicographically compares the values in the stack

Therefore they will compare the first elements, if those are equal move to the second elements, etc.

You can read more about lexicographical comparsion [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare).

> Lexicographical comparison is an operation with the following properties:
>
> - Two ranges are compared element by element.
> - The first mismatching element defines which range is lexicographically less or greater than the other.
> - If one range is a prefix of another, the shorter range is lexicographically less than the other.
> - If two ranges have equivalent elements and are of the same length, then the ranges are lexicographically equal.
> - An empty range is lexicographically less than any non-empty range.
> - Two empty ranges are lexicographically equal.